# Computer shuts down by itself

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, fan, asus-laptop, zenbook

I recently bought the  computer **Asus Zenbook UX410UA-GV410T** Ultrabook (Intel Core i7, 8 Go de RAM, SSD 256 Go, Windows 10).

The installation worked well. However, when I switch on my computer, the **fan turns (too) fast** making a lot of noise. After **4-5 minutes**, the computer **turns off by itself**. So it is impossible to keep my computer on.

Do you have any idea of how to solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check CPU temp in the bios, usually by pressing delete or f12 at start up. It should say at the bottom. But I would definitely contact Asus and explain your issue. This is not normal.

I recently contacted Asus support about a faulty sound card and they gave me a free shipping label and it was back within the week.

Make sure to tell them you should not and will not pay for shipping of their faulty products back to them.

You may also be able to bring it to the retailer where you purchased it if you had any kind of warrenty.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

By your description it may be overheating and switching off after reaching its maximum temperature. To confirm this, open any software that monitors the temperature and monitor it.

If that's the problem, you can try to change the thermal paste of the cpu.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I don't have enough time to download a software before the computer shuts down by itself. Do you know if there is something pre-installed on Windows 10 to get fastly the temperature?

Comment: You can check the cpu temperature directly in the BIOS before boot but the cpu will be idle, it may not generate enough heat to shut down.

Comment: Return it to the seller. It is not capable of serving as a Windows computer.

Comment: @K7AAY, well you could use it with Windows for a few minutes after it finishes booting.  :-)